# I have multiple useEffect, listeners or handlers of service but in the same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

please help me with this question please i have multiple useEffect and handler of services like subscriptions, listener of network state, listener of state of redux, and other things the component have more of 400 lines, but in same component, the component is located in the home of app, but return null, just handle this services, i want know if this is right, and not is a bad practice, if this is incorrect, what is correct way for handle this kind listener or services directed for all the app there are a little example:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'

export default function handlerServices() {

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
    setStateReduxNetwork(state);
  });
},[])
useEffect(() => {
  getInitialDeepLink();
   
  return () => {
    linkingSub.remove();
  };
}, []);
.....

.....
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessarily bad practice. I've heard this called a 'utility component'.  There are a couple of ways to possibly improve it.

1. Split up the component by function so it's easier to trace errors. E.g. `NetworkStateComponent`, `LinkingComponent`, etc.
2. Use an async action handling library like redux-sagas. I recommend that one if you already use redux and you need more handling than subscribe/unsubscribe.

This might also be a better question for the [code review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yes, already use redux and sagas, i try use custom hooks for that, but the dependency of react state is the cause of problem for divide in simple functions or helpers, but there  can i use sagas?

Comment: I tank for your answer, but i don't get it how i can divide in función like suggest, if the most of this services have the dependency of redux state, could you explain this suggest? please

Comment: Sure. You could start running a saga in the background when your app loads that waits for an to start the network listener. Use an event emitter to pass data from the network listener to redux. Inside your new saga, race two actions: one for receiving the network info from the event emitter, and one to unsubscribe. Handle both cases. Does that make sense? I can post some code later if you like.

Comment: As for dividing the functions into separate components, just make a new component and move things from that category into it. You can get state the same way as you are now, by using selectors.

Comment: I appreciate your help, don't have much experience with sagas, if is posible help me  with the example.

Comment: Sure, [let me know if this helps](https://codepen.io/256hz/pen/yLzrWNz).  This draws on concepts from the docs, for example [channels](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels) and [racing effects](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RacingEffects).

Comment: Than you very much for your help.